# Sharing Vuex State between Multiple Nuxt Apps

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js

I've been working on multiple `Nuxt` apps (part of one large saas app), one app manages the "admin panel" and the other app manages the "front end". I've made this separation because both apps are fairly complex in their nature.

I've been using nuxt native `auth` module (https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) for handling user authentication.

The issue here is that when a user is logged-in in the "admin panel" the "front-end" app has no clue of user auth state (obviously since they are technically two different apps).

Now, I want to share the `vuex` store state of "admin panel" with the "front end" app, in general, and auth state in specific. So I can display logged-in user name and a user-specific menu on the "front-end" app, when he/she is logged in.

Any idea how to go about it?